# Check if one column matches all objects in a list from another column

Tags: python, string, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe with one column of strings and another with a list of strings.

```
                     0                     1
0      apples are good      [orange, banana]
1     bananas are good        [bananas, bad]
2  cucumbers are green      [cucumbers, are]
3     grapes are green  [grapes, are, green]
4     oranges are good             [oranges]
5   pineapples are big     [flowers, apples]
```

I want the find all the indices where the string in `Column 0` matches all the list contents in `Column 1`. In this case the output would look like:

```
                     0                     1
2  cucumbers are green      [cucumbers, are]
3     grapes are green  [grapes, are, green]
4     oranges are good             [oranges]
```

I know I can use `pandas.Series.str.contains` but that only works on a single list and I want to avoid iterating/looping if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension and Boolean indexing:

```
res = df[[all(word in x.split() for word in y) for x, y in zip(df[0], df[1])]]

print(res)

                     0                     1
2  cucumbers are green      [cucumbers, are]
3     grapes are green  [grapes, are, green]
4     oranges are good             [oranges]
```

Comment: I would venture that list comprehension qualifies as "iterating/looping" which OP wants to avoid.

Comment: @noslenkwah, Possibly. But I'm not sure it's possible to avoid loops here. You can sure hide loops in `pd.Series.str.contains`, but an `object` dtype series by definition cannot offer vectorised functionality.